# Looking for the appropriate syntax of a Fox H function

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting, spe

Working a problem on Mathematics Stack Exchange, in a [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3466684/can-the-integral-int-infty-0-fracdu1up1u-be-computed-only-with) fom @Maxim is given the expression that I am even unable to type properly with MathJax (I do not know why but a copy/paste does not produce the same result for the related Fox H function.

Being blind, after more than one hour of vain attempts, I cannot get it.

Could anhy one hep me and provide the proper syntax ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have posted this question to Wolfram Mathematica Meta StackExchange. Did you mean to post it to Mathematics StackExchange? Or do you indeed want Wolfram Mathematica code? Anyhow, you can get TeX code by right-clicking on the equation, then Show Math As > TeX Commands. It is `H_{2, 2}^{2, 2} {\left(1 \middle|  {(0, 1), (0, p) \atop (0, 1), (0, p)} \right)}.` If you want Mathematica code: `FoxH[{{{0, 1}, {0, p}}}, {{{0, 1}, {0, p}}}, z]`.

Comment: @Domen. Thanks for answering. I don't know why but I was unable to copy/paste the MathJax formula. My problem was just to have the syntax to continue working. Being blind added to the complexity of some syntax does not make life easy. I put in Meta since it is not really a question. Thanks again & cheers